# How to prevent a form from processing null values before its filled in and submitted

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I have a simple  login .jsp page which calls a method which returns a html form.

However because the form action="Login.jsp" the form submits null values for all the fields before a user can fill it in.

```
request.getParameter("userName"); is always initially null
```

The second time the form works as expected. How can i prevent this from happening.

I need the action to be ="Login.jsp" as there are other things beign fired from this page.

login.jsp

```
<%
GenHTML genUIOb = new GenHTML(); 
out.println("" + genUIOb.generateLoginUI()); 
%>
```

GenHTML.java

```
  public String generateLoginUI()
  {
    String result="";

    result += "<form  action="Login.jsp"> . .name="userNmae" .  .</form>";

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: _have a simple login .jsp page which calls a method which returns a html form_ how do you do that ??show us some code ??

Comment: Ok sorry @SanKrish can  you help ?

Answer (score 0):

> result += " . .name="userNmae" .  .";

I think you have code as

```
<input type="text" name="userNmae">
```

just add value="Aaron" attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="userNmae" value="Aaron">
```